# The most generic datatype in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, any

I searched first for what I am looking for and this is the first time in my life to ask a coding question on the web. I hope I am doing it right.

I need to create an array of literally anything on swift.
For example:

```
let myArr:[Any] = [4, somestruct1, somestruct2]
```

-> this works fine

but I also need an array of an array without even specifying a certain dimension of that array, such as:

```
let myArr:[Any] = [4, [somestruct1, somestruct2], [5, [4.5, somestruct3]]]
```

I thought `[Any]` would be capable of representing arrays but the compiler complains about this syntax.

What can I do to represent a collection of anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of swift cannot find the type of [5, [4.5, ss()]]

```
struct ss {} // a structure
let myArr1: [Any] = [4, [ss(), ss()], [5, [4.5, ss()]]] // Don't compile
```

Now we inform the compiler about the type of the array when the context is ambiguous :

```
let myArr2: [Any] = [4, [ss(), ss()], ([5, ([4.5, ss()] as [Any])] as [Any])]
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy , I realised now my question is dumb :D